# Objective-C: add subview only work for one view

Tags: ios, objective-c

For each UIImageView, I want to add the label subview to it.
Here is my class inherited form UIImageView

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
if (self=[super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    self.categoryLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, 50)];

    self.categoryLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.categoryLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    self.categoryLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    [self addSubview:self.categoryLabel];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.subviews);
}
return self;
}
-(void)setModel:(HorizontalModel *)model
{
 _model=model;
 self.categoryLabel.text=self.model.category;
 [self sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"XXXXX%@",self.model.imgURL]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"obama"]];
  }
```

Here is my code in the view controller.

```
-(void)addImage:(NSNotification *)notification
{
self.HArrayLists=notification.userInfo[@"array"];
for (int i=0; i<[self.HArrayLists count]; i++) {
    JTImageView *imageView=[[JTImageView alloc]   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*310, 0, 300, 200)];
    imageView.model=[HorizontalModel restaurantsDetailWithDict: self.HArrayLists[i]];
    [self.mediaScrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
self.mediaScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(310*[self.HArrayLists count], 0);

}
```

It turns out that only the first imageView shows a label, while the rest of the imageViews show only images.

Comment: Are you sure all the data in HArrayLists include the text for all entries? Just to debug, you can do like this first: imageView.categoryLabel.text = @"Test"; and comment out the imageView.model= part. Most probably your data is @"", so there is nothing to show

Comment: agree with Rocotilos; also consider to use -enumerateObjectsUsingBlock method of self.HArrayLists; it looks much cleaner

 [self.HArrayLists enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^ (HArrayListsInst* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL* stop) {
              
 }];

Comment: why you are seeing self.mediaScrollView hight to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the core of your problem is the line:

```
self.categoryLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, 50)];
```

You are offsetting the x and y positions of the label by the x and y values of the image. This will place them outside the area of the image and with the image clipping, make them invisible. I think the line should be

```
self.categoryLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, 50)];
```

to place all the labels at the top left corner of each image.

Having said that there are also a number of recommendations I would like to offer.

Firstly make all variable names start with a lowercase. So `self.HArrayLists` should be `self.hArrayLists`.

Secondly try and make variable names match their contents. So again looking at `self.HArrayLists`, perhaps something like `self.imageData`.

Next I would have done the composition differently. I would have a `UIView` to which I add both the `UILabel` and `UIImageView` instances. Using a parent view like this to layout two sub views often makes life easier.

I would also look into using a `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewController` rather than a `UIScrollView`. It will take you a bit of work to get your heads around how collection views work. But you will gain in terms of performance and better layout management.

Finally, study up on constraints. They're an essential part of building modern apps that can easily adapt to different sized screens, rotation and layouts.

Comment: Also, you could use the bounds instead of frame, as this inside of the view, not outside which is what it sounds like you are wanting.  I like the suggestion here of using a UICollectionView instead.  It will do exactly what you are wanting it here, and as drekka stated you gain a lot in the terms of performance and layout management.  The gains for making use of dequeueCellWithReuseIdentifer() are pretty amazing!:) [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set as `categoryLabel`'s `frame` properly.

```
self.categoryLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, 50)];
```